# OCaml pattern matching type error

Tags: types, pattern-matching, ocaml

I have this segment of a function:

```
and interpret_read (id:string) (mem:memory)
               (inp:string list) (outp:string list)
: bool * memory * string list * string list =
  match inp with
  | [] -> raise (Failure "unexpected end of input")
  | head :: tail -> (true, (append mem (id, int_of_string head)), tail, outp)
```

The memory type is defined as follows:

```
type memory = (string * int) list;;
```

When I try to #use the source code I get the following error:

```
Error: This expression has type 'a * 'b
but an expression was epected of type (string * int) list
```

I'm still new to Ocaml so as I understand it 'a and 'b are generic types and they need to be defined as string and int before they can be appended to mem.  I feel like that understanding isn't completely accurate because if that were the case id should already be defined as a string and int_of_string head should be an int.  Can anyone help me clear up my confusion?

EDIT:
I have changed the function to the following:

```
and interpret_read (id:string) (mem:memory)
               (inp:string list) (outp:string list)
: bool * memory * string list * string list =
  match inp with
  | [] -> raise (Failure "unexpected end of input")
  | head :: tail -> (true, mem :: (id, int_of_string head), tail, outp)
```

And I receive the following error:

```
This expression has type memory = (string * int) list 
but an expression was expected of type string * int
```

This doesn't make sense to me because it's supposed to be of type memory.

If I change the function to the following:

```
    and interpret_read (id:string) (mem:memory)
               (inp:string list) (outp:string list)
: bool * memory * string list * string list =
  match inp with
  | [] -> raise (Failure "unexpected end of input")
  | head :: tail -> (true, (id, int_of_string head), tail, outp)
```

Then I get the following error:

```
This expression has type 'a * 'b 
but an expression was expected of type memory = (string * int) list
```

Which is what the the expression's type just was!  There's definitely something I'm missing here, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give a definition for `append`. If I assume this is `List.append`, its type is `'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list`. I.e., it takes two lists and returns a list. But you're passing a list and a single element (a pair).

Comment: Yes, sorry it is append.  How then do I append a single pair?

Comment: I suppose I would just use "::"?

Comment: I made a change to the OP, please take a look if you have the time

Comment: Yes, to add an element `x` to the beginning of a list `xs` you can write `x :: xs`. Your second try has the list first then the element. Your latest code just has the element, no list.